# Proof by Induction: The Cartesian product of a denumerable set A and a finite set B are denumerable

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Assume A is finite and B is denumerable then AxB is denumerable.

Let n=A>0

Argue by induction on N.

Basic step: n=1: {(A1,B1),(A1,B2),...,(A1,Bk)} <-is denumerable

n:

{(A1,B1),...,(A1,Bk),(A2,B1),...,(A2,Bk),...(An,Bk)}

n+1:

{(A1,B1),...,(A1,Bk),(A2,B1),...,(A2,Bk),(An,B1),...,(An,Bk),(An+1,B1),...,(An+1,Bk)}

I'm not quite sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

If $Card(A)=n+1$, then $A=C\cup \{a_{n+1}\}$ with $Card(C)=n$.

Can you now write $A \times B$ has the union of two denumerable set, $C \times B$ as in the $n$-th step, and $\{a_{n+1}\} \times B$ as in the first step ? And the union of two denumerable sets being denumerable...

Comment: Would there be a proof necessary to show that CxB is denumerable? because we would be trying to show (CxB) U {An+1}xB, or are we just assuming that (AxB) is denumerable is true

Comment: @Soo lee : not sure what you mean. CxB is denumerable according to your induction hypothesis. The union of two denumerable sets being denumerable is a standard property, usually one of the very first you see just after learning the definition of denumerable. (if you want to prove it, just number one set with odd numbers and the other set with even numbers...)

Answer (score 0):

You can prove a stronger statement.

See the link below

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cartesian_Product_of_Countable_Sets_is_Countable